# Rails Model changes causing full Zeus restart

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin, zeus

Whenever I save a Rails model while running Zeus, the Zeus server appears to be completely reloading. The Zeus output generally turns yellow ("waiting") for about 10 seconds. This only happens with some models. I have yet to figure out the difference between the models.

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

**Edit:**
Removing `ActiveAdmin.routes(self)` from my routes.rb file fixed the issue. ActiveAdmin no longer works, obviously. Haven't found a workaround yet.

Answer (score 1):

by default zeus is watching the files changing... so if you save a model without even anything changed in it... zeus will think it had been changed and therefore restart to reflect the latest changes done... so that you don't have to restart rails to see the changes.

and zeus excels when you change a test file... it only restart the test environment.. so that you can run your tests as fast as possible

and as documented in this [issue](https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/433) this is how it works.

**Extra Info**

**in some cases** when you add a new file ( model or config) zeus doesn't automatically restart.. and doesn't reflect the latest changes.. in these cases you have to restart it your self

Comment: Right, but it should only reload that one model, not refresh the entire Zeus server. My problem is that the entire server is restarting when saving SOME models, but not others.

Comment: @MattFordham i've edited the answer adding this "and as documented in this [issue](https://github.com/burke/zeus/issues/433) this is how it works."